# how do I find the limit

Tags: limits, functions, piecewise-continuity

$\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)$, $\lim_{x\to1^-}  f(x)$, and $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$, where

$f(x)= \begin{cases} 2x+1 & \mbox{if } x≤1 \\ 4-x^2 & \mbox{if } x>1 \end{cases}$

I do not understand how to solve this question, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you understand or don't understand? You know how to compute limits for simple (non-piecewise) functions, I assume. Do you know how to compute left and right hand limits? Do you understand how $f(x)$ is defined? Do you know what the graph of $f(x)$ looks like?

Answer (score 0):

So the question wants you to calculate the limit coming from the left and right, then limit overall. If the limit coming from the left is not the same as the limit coming from the right, then the overall limit does not exist. Does this help?

In this case,

$$\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} (2x+1).$$

$$\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 1^{+}} (4-x^2).$$

Comment: So I would just substitute -1 to find the limit at 2x-1 and +1 to find the limit at 4-x^2 right? What would I do for the over all limit which in this case is 1? Thanks for your help!

Comment: as written by me (i don't know the exact original question, one substitutes 1 for $x$ and the left limit is 3, the right limit is 3, and the overall limit is 3 since they agree. $1^-$ means a number just less than 1, not -1.